# How to insert multiple records/rows in MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js

Is it possible in Sails.js to insert multiple records?
I am using MySQL, I need to save 'n' rows into MySQL depending upon request coming from API.

I need help with respect to Sails.js
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can write multiple records in mysql at once.
let my model is:

```
module.exports = {
  tableName:'test',
  autoCreatedAt:false,
  autoUpdatedAt:false,
  attributes: {
    name:'string'
  }
};
```

First let's see how is it done in mysql query.

```
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (1,'AB'),(2,'ABCCDC');
```

Now this is how you can add multiple records...

```
Test.create([{name:'name1'},{name:'name2'},{name:'name3'}])
  .exec(function(err,done){
    if(err){
      //hendle the error;
      return;
    }
    //successfully inserted;
  });
```

Now i guess my point is clear.

> you just have to pass the `array of objects in model.create()` to insert multiple objects.

Comment: Note that this is the way to insert multiple rows regardless of database (works with MySQL, Mongo, disk, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @sgress454 for pointing this out, I have to implement the same in Mongodb as well [upvoted]